# Import-SPWeb : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. At line:1 char:13

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to migrate a site under a sitecollection from one server to site collection in another server but I'm getting this error on SharePoint 2010 Management Shell (Administrator)

[image]

When I checked the import logs, below is the report

> [27/2/2014 2:38:06 PM] Start Time: 27/2/2014 2:38:06 PM. [27/2/2014
>   2:38:06 PM] Progress: Initializing Import. [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM]
>   Progress: Starting content import. [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] Progress:
>   De-Serializing Objects to Database. [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] [Web] [AC]
>   Progress: Importing [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] [Web] [AC]   Verbose:
>   Importing Web https://intranet.cimbsg.cimbdomain.com/sites/ITD/test.
>   [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] [Web] [AC]   Error: Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation. [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] [Web] [AC]   Debug:
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions
>   permissionMask)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Update()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector) [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM] FatalError:
>   Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. [27/2/2014 2:39:21 PM]
>   Debug:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions
>   permissionMask)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Update()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type
>   objectType, Boolean isChildObject)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type
>   objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run() [27/2/2014 2:39:22 PM]
>   Progress: Import did not complete. [27/2/2014 2:39:22 PM] Finish Time:
>   27/2/2014 2:39:22 PM. [27/2/2014 2:39:22 PM] Duration: 00:01:16
>   [27/2/2014 2:39:22 PM] Finished with 0 warnings. [27/2/2014 2:39:22
>   PM] Finished with 2 errors.

Don't have any idea what i'm missing.

Comment: Looks like user performing the import does not have enough privileges to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permission error - are you sure you do not lack any necessary priveledges for the site you are trying to import data to?

*edited my answer: Make sure you have full rights to the site and also shell admin rights on the content database of the site.

Comment: both servers has full Read.  is there anything else?

Comment: Well, since this is import - as in import data TO SharePoint, I would probably expect that it needs you to have shell admin rights to the content databases.